# Can't add more registers if having update code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm learning EF, and I'm making an exercise where I got three tables, one of Files that has many documents and those documents have many images. My tables are Expediente (File), Documento (Documents) and Archivos (images).

I have a form where I list in a datagridview all my files, if you choose, one that already exists, then you should be able too add more documents into that file, the thing is I can't do it if I add my code to update. If try to add 1 new document, nothing happens doesn't save changes to the db neither throws and exception, but if I try adding 2 or more, it throws the following exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Attaching an entity of type 'Entidad.Documento' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

the code is as follows:

```
foreach (var documento in documentos)
{
    if (documento.idDocumento == 0)
    {
        context.Documentos.Add(documento);
    }
    else
    {
        var entry = context.Entry(documento);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            context.Documentos.Attach(documento);
        }
    }
}
```

the error shows when attaching the document.

this is just a function that returns void, it works only to save, it recieve a BindingList that contains all the documents recieved from the db and the ones I'm adding.

Regards!

Comment: Is this not clear enough: *Attaching an entity of type 'Entidad.Documento' failed because another entity of the **same type already has the same primary key** value.*?

Comment: you mean my question is not clear or the exception? if it is the exception that's what I get.

Comment: I am asking that do you not understand the exception? It clearly tells you what the problem is.

Comment: yeah, I do understand the exception, what I don't understand is why am I getting it. If you see my error in my code I'd appreciate if you tell me.

Comment: I mean, if I update a register it works fine, the problem is when I try to add 2 or more documents.

Comment: You cannot add more than 1 document with the same primary key. Make sure they have different primary keys.

Comment: And how exactly I'm I supposed to do that? And why if that's the problem, when I click save button and execute that code with no new documents I don't get the exception? it simply don't do nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had to change the method in which I was updating my fields I did this and it worked:

```
if (documento.idDocumento == 0)
                    {
                        context.Documentos.Add(documento);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Documento updDoc = context.Documentos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.idDocumento == documento.idDocumento);
                        updDoc.NombreDocumento = documento.NombreDocumento;
                    }
```